# Database Migrations on Firebase Realtime Database Online Data

Tags: kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, migration, data-class

I have the following data class

```
data class User (
    override var id: String = "",
    var userId: String = "",
    var userRole: Int = 0,
    var firstName: String = "",
    var lastName: String = "",
    var emailAddress: String = "",
    var gender: String = "",
    var dateOfBirth: String = "",
    var timeStamp: TimeStamp = TimeStamp(),
    var status: Status = Status()
): CommonModel()
```

I want to add a new property

```
var notes: Map<String,String> = mapOf()
```

When I do, I am no longer able to retrieve the existing users from Firebase Realtime database as the existing online data does not contain the notes field.

The following line nolonger work,

```
val user = dataSnapshot.getValue(
                            User::class.java
)
```

The line of code triggers the follwoing error,

[image: Error Screenshot]

How do we handle such data class modifications?

Comment: "I am no longer able to retrieve the existing users from Firebase Realtime database" Why not? What happens when you try? Is there an error message?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have editted the question and added the screenshot. It brings up a conversion error for HashMap to string.

Comment: This looks like a type mismatch, where one side has a primitive string value where the other side has/expects a dictionary with key/value pairs. Check the JSON of the node that is causing this error message to find the type mismatch.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have been able to clear the error following your suggestion. Thank you for your assistance